# Python global empty in class

Tags: python, arrays, scope, global

I tried to get array parameters values in another class , where and why i wrong here ?

> My second python file => myModule.py :

```
parameters  = ([])

class MyFirstClass():
    def __init__(self, params):
        global parameters
        parameters = params

class MySecondClass():
    def __init__(self):
        global parameters
        print parameters


class MyClassWhereIHaveAProblem(http.HTTPFactory):
    proto = .....
    global parameters
    print parameters  **// array is empty here**

class start_server():
     def __init__(self, params):
        self.x_params = params[0] //ip
        self.y_params = int(params[1]) //port
        global parameters 
        parameters = params[2]
     def start():
         reactor.listenTCP(self.y, MyClassWhereIHaveAProblem(), interface=self.x)
```

> My first python file => Handle.py :

```
from myModule import MyFisrtClass
from myModule import MySecondClass
from myModule import MyClassWhereIHaveAProblem
from myModule import start_server

class Handle():
    def __init__(self):
        params = (["vector1", "vector2"])
        self.params = (["127.0.0.1","3128", params])
    def go_to_another(self):
        s = start_server(self.params)
        s.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    H = Handle()
    H.go_to_another()
```

I tried to get array parameters values in another class , where and why i wrong here ?

Comment: Why do you have the list surrounded by brackets? What are your trying to accomplish here? Does it not make sense? Do you get an error?

Comment: And what is wrong with your code? What's the main goal here?

Comment: If you need tuple of list (why?!) - you have to add comma - _([],)_, otherwise you external brackets are redudant and serve the only purpose of confusing reades

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are simply:

- forgetting the second set of double underscores for the special method names
- making typos in the class names, you had "First" spelled "Fisrt"
- you never did anything to use the `MySecondClass` class, so I initialized one in your main routine with:  `y = MySecondClass()`

> Handle.py:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python 

from myModule import MyFirstClass
from myModule import MySecondClass

class Handle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.params = (["ele1","ele2","ele3"])
    def go_to_another(self):
        X = MyFirstClass(self.params)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    H = Handle()
    H.go_to_another()
    y = MySecondClass()
```

> myModule.py:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

parameters = ([])

class MyFirstClass():
    def __init__(self, params):
        global parameters
        parameters = params

class MySecondClass():
    def __init__(self):
        global parameters
        print 'this should not be empty: %s' % parameters  # array is no longer empty here
```

> Output:

```
this should not be empty: ['ele1', 'ele2', 'ele3']
```

Comment: The purpose of _global_ - preserve variable reference when assigning it a value in function (bad idea). When you want to reference a global variable in a Python, it searches external scopes automatically, so that _global_ is redundant.

Comment: ho yes , but it's not my real code , in my real i'have the double underscores ...excuse me ...

Comment: @Aborted-Security In this code, the "parameters" array is not empty. I also initialized an instance of your "MySecondClass" class. What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: @Alex.B , thanks for your time,  I want: handle.py, init class of a module, assign an overall value to finally use this global value in another class. I do not know if I'm clear, thank you again.

Comment: I think the code I posted does that. I changed 3 things in your code: * fixed spelling mistakes, * fixed double underscores, and * actually initialize a `MySecondClass`

Comment: I change my question to be more specific. dsl

Comment: @Aborted-Security I am still having trouble understanding, all you are trying to do is read the global variable from a class other than the one that initialized it. The code I posted does that.

Comment: @Alex.B I have finally modified the code of THIS page .... it's more clear ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have  `X = MyFisrtClass(self.params)` instead of `X = MyFirstClass(self.params)`! Also `__init` should be `__init__`.

Comment: ho yes , but it's not my real code , in my real i'have the double underscores ...excuse me

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the variable when the class is first defined, but defining the variable when the class is initialized.

In Python, anything here:

```python
class MyClass:
    # here
```

Is evaluated as soon as the interpreter reaches that line-- **not when the class is initialized**.

Try running this code to get a better idea of what I mean:

```
my_global_var = 'set initially!'

class MyClass():

    # Will print 'set initially', as this 
    # print statement is run before an instance of the 
    # class ever gets initialized,
    print 'in class defn: %s' % my_global_var

    def __init__( self ):
        global my_global_var 
        my_global_var = 'set by the class instance!'

x = MyClass()

# Will print 'set by the class instance', as now
# you are printing it after the class has been initialized
# at least once
print 'after class is initialized: %s' % my_global_var
```

For your code:

```
# I have a problem here
class MyClassWhereIHaveAProblem(http.HTTPFactory):
    #proto = .....
    #global = parameters
    print 'not set here, this is static: %s' % parameters  #**// array is empty here**

    def __init__(self):
        print 'now it is set: %s' % parameters
```

But make sure you actually initialize one of those `MyClassWhereIHaveAProblem`.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, but did you not there a way to declare (without __init__) a list of such global way? the real source of my problem is: reactor.listenTCP (port, MyClassWhereIHaveAProblem (), interface = "ip"), I can not pass parameters to the object: http.HTTPFactory. Or rather, I do not know how. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "pass parameters"? Normally you would do that with `__init__`. Then you could do something like `MyClassWhereIHaveAProblem( ip_addr )`. When you initialize a new class, you are calling its `__init__`. I don't think I understand you, could you please come up with a minimal example that explains what you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

From [what I think is the documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTCP.html):

```python
listenTCP(port, factory, backlog=50, interface='')
```

- **port**  a port number on which to listen
- **factory**   a twisted.internet.protocol.ServerFactory instance
- **backlog**   size of the listen queue
- **interface** The local IPv4 or IPv6 address to which to bind; defaults to `''`, ie all IPv4 addresses. To bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, you must call this method twice.

So I think you want to simply do:

```
listenTCP(self.y_params, YourProblemClass(), interface=self.x_params)
```

Where:
- `y_params` is what you called the **port**, and
- `x_params` is what you called the **address**.

Comment: Here too you are absolutely right (I'm fast and I forget to do this properly, dsl). I correct my code last time to correct this.But this does not change my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I'll go to sleep :) I had also itinialise my object (logical), now everything is ok, Thanks for your time Alex.B, solution here:

```
class MyClassWhereIHaveAProblem(http.HTTPFactory):
    proto = .....
    def __init__(self):
        http.HTTPFactory.__init__(self)
        global parameters
        print parameters
```